# How to remove a combination of characters from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

For Example, I am having a string like:

```
string str = "santhosh,ravi,phani,praveen,sathish,prakash";
```

Now , I need to remove `,phani` from `str`.
can any one help me?
I tried by using `trim` and `substring`.but I am not getting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following,

```
str = str.Replace(",phani", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Won't work if you want to remove the word "phani" when it's at the beginning and will also remove words that only start with "phani".

Comment: Yes it wont work, you can make use of Regex to replace that kinda of stuffs

Comment: If I want to delete only the first occurance? then what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method for that;

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

```
string str = "santhosh,ravi,phani,praveen,sathish,prakash";
str = str.Replace(",phani", "");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/V9AVGb)**.